# Error installing labelImg

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am getting below error while trying to install [labelImg](https://github.com/tzutalin/labelImg#macos). Below are the steps I am doing.

```
administrators-MacBook-Pro:labelImg-master amit.sood$ brew install qt

Warning: qt 5.10.0_1 is already installed

administrators-MacBook-Pro:labelImg-master amit.sood$ brew install libxml2

Warning: libxml2 2.9.7 is already installed

administrators-MacBook-Pro:labelImg-master amit.sood$ make qt5py3

pyrcc5 -o resources.py resources.qrc

administrators-MacBook-Pro:labelImg-master amit.sood$ python labelImg.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "labelImg.py", line 1353, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "labelImg.py", line 1349, in main
    app, _win = get_main_app(argv)
  File "labelImg.py", line 1342, in get_main_app
    'data', 'predefined_classes.txt'))
  File "labelImg.py", line 399, in __init__
    self.filePath = ustr(defaultFilename)
  File "/Users/amit.sood/Documents/Analytics/github/labelImg-master/libs/ustr.py", line 7, in ustr
    from PyQt4.QtCore import QString
ImportError: No module named PyQt4.QtCore
administrators-MacBook-Pro:labelImg-master amit.sood$
```

Comment: Did you try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28632169/qgis-pyqt4-missing-qstring-class ?