# How to access QString for QGIS-2.14 in PyQt4

Tags: python, pyqt4, python-import, qgis, qstring

This is a bit QGIS specific, but figure it's kind of low level so I've posted here. I can definitely move this over to gis.stackexchange.com if that's better.

Trying to use [QgsRasterCalculator](https://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsRasterCalculator.html#a2d6223859ab758438290edc674ad0362), which seems to want a QString type object for a couple of arguments. I try to create a QString ([like described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1400885/2101132)) but get:

```
import PyQt4
PyQt4.QtCore.QString('foo')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'QString'
```

So I try to use a regular string for my first argument (`calc = QgsRasterCalculator( 'demffac > 120', newStreams, 'GTiff', rFac.extent(), rFac.crs().authid(), rFac.height(), rFac.width(), entries)`), I got:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  QgsRasterCalculator(QString, QString, QString, QgsRectangle, int, int, list-of-QgsRasterCalculatorEntry): argument 5 has unexpected type 'unicode'
  QgsRasterCalculator(QString, QString, QString, QgsRectangle, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem, int, int, list-of-QgsRasterCalculatorEntry): argument 5 has unexpected type 'unicode'
  QgsRasterCalculator(QgsRasterCalculator): argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'`

I'm using QGIS 2.14, which has been [documented as using QString](https://qgis.org/api/2.14/qgsrastercalculator_8h.html) (as I understand it). I've tried to use the `sip` package to reset ([per these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28632169/qgis-pyqt4-missing-qstring-class)) but QGIS's python console doesn't seem to want to change (`ValueError: API 'QString' has already been set to version 2`).

Any way to make my `QgsRasterCalculator()` call work? Thanks for any info!

/*==================**EDIT: screen grab of my QGIS's responses to suggestions**=========
[image]
/*==================
Version info:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QT_VERSION_STR
from PyQt4.pyqtconfig import Configuration

print("Qt version:", QT_VERSION_STR)
('Qt version:', '4.8.5')
cfg = Configuration()
print("SIP version:", cfg.sip_version_str)
('SIP version:', '4.14.7')
print("PyQt version:", cfg.pyqt_version_str)
('PyQt version:', '4.10.2')
```

Comment: Hi @ekhumoro. Sorry for delayed response. No, your answer did not work for my configuration of QGIS 2.14.6 (aside from adding plugins, I haven't really messed w/the default settings or configuration). I'll add a screen grab to show what I'm seeing.

Comment: The QString issue is a red herring. The real error is actually caused by one of the *non*-QStirng arguments. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looking more closely at the traceback, it seems that `QgsRasterCalculator` does not require the use of `QString`. This is proved by the fact that you passed python strings for the first three arguments, and the error message does not complain about them at all. Rather, it complains about the ***fifth*** argument, which must be either an `int` or `QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem` object, whereas you seem to be passing in `unicode` or `str` objects. Why are you passing in the return value of `rFac.crs().authid()`? Surely you should be passing in `rFac.crs()`, rather than `authid()` (which is [documented as returning a string](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.html#ab2dee1805d8e3b62448e4d106753b595)).

---

With regard to potential issues with `QString`:

When used with Python2, PyQt4 most definitely does have the `QString` class - unless you take explicit steps to change that [by using the sip module](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/incompatible_apis.html). The code at the beginning of your question is not what you actually ran, because it does not raise that specific error:

```
Python 2.7.15 (default, Jun 27 2018, 13:05:28)
[GCC 8.1.1 20180531] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import PyQt4
>>> PyQt4.QtCore.QString('foo')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'QtCore'
```

If you import the `QtCore` module properly, the code works fine:

```
>>> from PyQt4 import QtCore
>>> QtCore.QString('foo')
PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'foo')
```

Note that it never makes sense to import the `PyQt4` package on its own. It is just an empty namespace which (for performance reasons) imports the other modules lazily. You must therefore always import the Qt modules explicitly as I have done above.

PS:

In the second half of your question, it seems that the PyQt APIs have somehow already been changed to version 2, which will ***switch off*** support for `QString`. To switch it back on, you would need to do:

```
import sip
sip.setapi('QString', 1)
```

However, this step must be done ***before*** any other PyQt modules are imported.